# Accessing partitions between Ubuntu and Fedora

Tags: boot, partitioning, filesystems, multi-boot

I installed a dual boot with Fedora 19 and Ubuntu 13.10 in the same machine. I am able to mount the other partitions from both of the OSs. I'm planning to use all the unzipped applications in Fedora `/home/usr/` partition and use it in Ubuntu and vice versa, by editing the env variables.

Will it cause any harm/damage the filesystems as both OSs are journaling/indexing other OS partitions? Are there any side effects of using other OS partitions in a dual boot computer? Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only notice here is for UserID stored/checked in file permissions.

Ubuntu gives UIDs starting from 1000, Redhat from 500. You need to have user with the same UID in both OS'es (or use su/sudo for skipping all checks at all).

Useful commands:

- `id [username]` checks current UID,
- `useradd -u 1001 ... username` assigns UID explicitly when creates new user,
- `usermod -u 1001 username` changes UID of existing user.
  Do not forget "`chmod -R username ~username`" after that!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. As I understood correctly. You mean If the user id is same in both the OS users which are manipulating the files of other OS partitions there will be no issues. Also journaling / indexing will not have any side effects of data being lost or correct, right. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, applications are generally stored in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and `/usr/local/bin`, not in `/home`. (The main exceptions are programs that you write yourself.) Thus, you're starting from a non-standard configuration. That's not necessarily wrong in any absolute sense, but when you fight the current like that, you're likely to end up wasting a lot of time and effort. At a minimum, you'll need to reconfigure things like paths. Package systems (RPM and Debian packages) won't manage your applications, so you'll end up wasting a lot of time doing things manually that the package system does automatically. Some programs may make assumptions that will create program-specific problems, too.

Another issue is that different distributions often use different support libraries. For instance, Fedora might use GenericLib 2.87, whereas Ubuntu might use GenericLib 3.02. That difference could mean that a binary compiled for Ubuntu won't work under Fedora and vice-versa.

Overall, I'd have to advise against doing as you're suggesting. Instead, ask a question that directly addresses what you hope to accomplish. Are you trying to save administrative effort, keep software in sync between the two distributions, save disk space, or what? There are likely to be better ways to accomplish such goals, or reasons why the concerns are unwarranted.

Comment: Hi Rod Smith, Thanks for taking time and giving me the information. Here I'm not expecting any use from the software between the two OS. Most of my applications I want to use as extracted software and setting the env variables. I'm not bothering about accessing software installed through rpm. I mean I just worried about file corruption because I'm accessing partitions between OS and I' not sure that journaling / indexing of OS may corrupt or sometime unecessary results or not.

Comment: If at all possible, you should use your distribution's package systems. They were invented for a reason: Keeping software up to date, including frequently-changing dependencies, quickly becomes a nightmare. For instance, Program A may depend on Libraries 1, 2, 3, and 4, while Program B may depend on Libraries 2, 3, 5, 6, and 7, and Program C may depend on both Program A and Libraries 6 and 8 (in addition to the Libraries 1, 2, 3, and 4 of Program A). When you upgrade libraries, therefore, you may need to upgrade the programs that depend on it, too. This can become a big hassle very quickly.